# inserting data to database does not load straight away

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, wpf

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace SolutionCW
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for addCustomer.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class addCustomer : Window
    {
        public addCustomer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) // add customer button
        {
            string inputName = nameinput.Text;
            string inputLastname = secondnameinput.Text;
            string Number = phonenumber.Text;
            string address = addressinput.Text;
            string Pcode = postcode.Text;

            string cmdstring = "INSERT INTO Customer (FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber, Address, Postcode) VALUES (@Name, @LastName, @Phone, @Addinput, @Pcode)";

            string connString = MainWindow.DBconnection;

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    comm.Connection = conn;
                    comm.CommandText = cmdstring;

                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", nameinput.Text);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", secondnameinput.Text);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", phonenumber.Text);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Addinput", addressinput.Text);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pcode", postcode.Text);

                    try
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        conn.Close();

                        Customer basic = new Customer();
                        basic.updateTable();
                    }
                    catch(SqlException)
                    {
                    }

                    this.Close();
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I have shown my code for adding a customer record from the form to my database, but when I press the add button, it does not show the newly entered data when it opens up the database. It only shows the newly entered record when I exit the database/refresh and go back in? any help appreciated, thanks

Comment: You haven’t shown any code that handles the refresh. If the insert works there’s nothing wrong with this code. But if you don’t reload the data from the database afterwards nothing new will be shown.

Comment: Thank you, is there anyway to refresh it or is it simple as basic.Refresh()?

Comment: Can’t say anything about that since I don’t know what that class does

Comment: edit question and share more info, maybe share code for displaying data?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're displaying your data.  However, the issue is your button event executes, then sends the data to the database, but the control that displays your data hasn't been re-rendered.  Depending on the type of control, will vary on the command to refresh.

```
// Form:
var form = new ApplicationForm();
form.Refresh();

// Update Panel:
updatePanelSample.Update();
```

Without more information on how you're displaying the data, we won't be able to help you update or redraw the rendered application to display the update.